# CKAN - filter datasets based on user

Tags: ckan

We are trying to learn/understand CKAN for a possible project.

Below is one of the possible scenario.

CKAN instance will have 2 datasets say **ds1** and **ds2** belonging to organization **org1**.

There are 2 members **mem1** and **mem2** both belonging to **org1**.

Both datasets, **ds1** and **ds2** are private.

As per docs, all the members of the organization will have access to private datasets.

We want **mem1** to view only **ds1 (not ds2)** and **mem2** to view only **ds2 (not ds1).**

Is this supported by CKAN OTB, any thoughts/pointers to docs is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported out the box. You would have to do a bit of a development to get things working as you described.

It may not be a perfect solution, but I would recommend you take a look at the Custom User Privileges Extension found [here](http://extensions.ckan.org/extension/customuserprivileges/).

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the response.